# A monoid presentation with invertible generators is a group presentation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-presentation, monoid

Let $M=\langle S\mid R\rangle$ be a presentation for a monoid. $R=\{a_1=b_1,...\}$ is a collection of equalities, and $M$ is defined as the set of equivalence classes under the the reflexive and transitive closure of the symmetric relation of rewriting $sa_it$ as $sb_it$ and vice versa.

If for any $x\in S$ there is some $I_x$ in the free monoid $S^*$ and some relation $(xI_x=e)\in R$, then how do we prove that $M$ is a group with group presentation $\langle S\mid R\rangle$?

Comment: What do you mean by "assume some of the relations are of the form xxxx"? What about the others?

Comment: A generator x is invertible means that there is some relation that starts/ends with x and is equal to 1, such as xxyz=1. This way, I can write x^-1=xyz.

Comment: Yes, and now I realized that it should be "first and last factor" because otherwise it isn't necessarily a group.

Comment: You can actually relax your condition somewhat. If all $x \in X$ are required by $R$ to have a right inverse, then $M$ will be a group. So you only need, for all $x \in X$, some equation of the form $x T = 1$ in $R$, where $T$ is some term. Or, dually, you could require that all $x$ have a left inverse.

Comment: @MarkSaving Does this actually work though? Consider the monoid with presentation <a,b,c,d,... | ab=bc=cd=de=...=1>, with infinite generators. Is this a group? I don't think so?

Comment: (nvm, ba=babc=bc=1)

Comment: @ZongshuWu Note that given a monoid $M$, $M’ = \{x \in M \mid \exists y (xy = 1)\}$ is a submonoid of $M$. If $M$ is generated by $X$ and all $X$ have a right inverse, then $M’ = M$. A monoid where all elements have a right inverse is a group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking for quite some time, I solved my question. For $w_1,w_2\in S^*$, write $w_1\sim w_2$ if it is possible to rewrite $w_1$ as $w_2$.

*Proof.* For any $w\in S^*$, write $w=x_1x_2...x_n$, where each $x_i\in S$, and define $I_w=I_{x_n}...I_{x_2}I_{x_1}$. The following calculation shows that $wI_w\sim e$.
\begin{align*}
 (x_1x_2...x_n)(I_{x_n}...I_{x_2}I_{x_1})&=(x_1...x_{n-1})(x_nI_{x_n})(I_{x_{n-1}}...I_{x_1})\\
 &\sim(x_1...x_{n-1})e(I_{x_{n-1}}...I_{x_1})\\
 &=(x_1...x_{n-2})(x_{n-1}I_{x_{n-1}})(I_{x_{n-2}}...I_{x_1})\\
 &\sim...\\
 &=x_1I_{x_1}\sim e.
\end{align*}
Now let $f$ be the natural monoid homomorphism $S^*\to M$. For every $a\in M$, we can write $a=f(w)$ where $w\in S^*$. Then $f(w)f(I_w)=f(wI_w)=f(e)=e$, thus $a$ has a right inverse. Since $a$ was arbitrary, every element has a right inverse, so $M$ is a group. Thus, we can extend $f$ to a group homomorphism $g:F_S\to M$, such that $f$ and $g$ agree on $S^*$.

Define $R'=\{w_1w_2^{-1}\in F_S:(w_1=w_2)\in R\}$. Then by definition, $\langle S\mid R\rangle$ (as a group presentation) is equal to the quotient of $F_S$ by the normal closure $N$ of $R'$. So now our goal is to show that $\ker g=N$, after which we will be done by the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Consider any $w_1w_2^{-1}\in R'$. We know that $w_1\sim w_2$, thus
$$g(w_1w_2^{-1})=g(w_1)g(w_2)^{-1}=f(w_1)f(w_2)^{-1}=f(w_2)f(w_2)^{-1}=e.$$
Hence $w_1w_2^{-1}\in\ker g$. Since $w_1w_2^{-1}$ was arbitrary, $R'\subseteq\ker g$. Since $\ker g$ is normal, $N\subseteq\ker g$ as well.

Conversely, consider any $w\in\ker g$, that is, $g(w)=e$. We want to show that $w\in N$, that is, $w$ can be obtained via inversion, multiplication by elements in $R'$ and conjugation. Write $w=y_1y_2...y_n$, where each $y_i$ is either a generator or the inverse of a generator. Next, define $z_i=y_i$ if $y_i$ is a generator, and $I_{y_i^{-1}}$ if $y_i^{-1}$ is a generator, so that $g(y_i)=f(z_i)$. Let $w'=z_1...z_n\in S^*$. Thus,
$$f(w')=f(z_1...z_n)=f(z_1)...f(z_n)=g(y_1)...g(y_n)=g(y_1...y_n)=g(w)=e.$$
So $w'\sim e$. We know that a sequence of rewrites turns $e$ into $w'$, so we follow them. In each case, $sw_1t$ is rewritten as $sw_2t$, where either $w_1w_2^{-1}\in R'$ or $w_2w_1^{-1}\in R'$. In both cases, we can use $w_1w_2^{-1}$. So
$$sw_2t=s((w_1w_2^{-1})^{-1}*s^{-1}(sw_2t)s)s^{-1}$$
We have used inversion, multiplication of elements in $R'$ and conjugation to get from the identity to $w'$. Therefore, $w'\in N$. Now, we use these actions to obtain $w$ from $w'$. Starting from $w'$, we successively change $z_i$ of the form $I_{y_i^{-1}}$ to the form $y_i$, like so:
$$Z_1y_iZ_2=Z_2^{-1}(Z_2(Z_1I_{y_i^{-1}}Z_2)Z_2^{-1}*(y_i^{-1}I_{y_i^{-1}})^{-1})Z_2$$
Therefore, $w\in N$ and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

Consider some such $X, R$, and consider some monoid/group $G$ and some inclusion function $i : X \to G$. We say $i$ comports with $R$ if for all equations $T_1(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = T_2(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ in $R$, we have $T_1(i(x_1), \ldots, i(x_n)) = T_2(i(x_1), \ldots, i(x_n))$.

Recall that the monoid/group with presentation $\langle X \mid R \rangle$ is the initial function $i \to M$ which comports with $R$. More formally, this is a monoid/group $M$, together with a canonical function $i : X \to M$ which comports with $R$, which has the following universal property:

> For all monoids/groups $G$ and all $j : X \to G$ which comports with $R$, there is a unique monoid/group homomorphism $f : M \to G$ such that $f \circ i = j$.

Note that this characterises $(M, i)$ uniquely up to unique isomorphism.

Critically, note that if $M$, $G$ are groups, a group homomorphism $M \to G$ is exactly a monoid homomorphism $M \to G$. Thus, it is easy to see that if $M, i$ is the monoid with presentation $\langle X \mid R \rangle$, and if moreover $M$ is a group, then $M, i$ also satisfies the universal property which characterises being the group with the presentation $\langle X \mid R \rangle$.

So yes, $M$ can indeed be given by this group presentation.

Comment: But how do I prove this universal property? Is there a proof using only the definition of the monoid and group presentations?